# How to set a cookie on a separate domain in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, cross-domain

How can you set a cookie on a different Domain that is calling my site with a javascript call?  It works in FF3, but not in IE6.

My server is called from a javascript tag on a seperate site and domain. The result returns javascript that populates their page with data (it's a widget).  I am trying to set a cookie using domain=".mydomain.com" and path="/".  It works for Firefox, but won't work in IE. It works fine in IE if I test the javascript call from my own domain.

Does anyone know how to get cross domain cookie setting to work in IE, using Rails?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As long as your server is setting a cookie within its own domain or from a subdomain of its domain, this should work

```
cookies[cookie_name] = {
   :value => 'a value',
   :expires => 1.year.from_now,
   :domain => 'example.com'
 }
```

It won't work for any other domains.

To get this to work in IE6 you may need a valid [P3P](http://www.w3.org/P3P/) policy header

Something like this sent as a header should do it:

```
headers["p3p"] = 'CP="CAO PSA OUR"'
```

Comment: that is how I set it: cookies[cookie_name] = { :value => 'x', :expires => 1.day.from_now, :domain => '.mydomain.com' }

And yes, it does work for firefox.  I actually thought it wouldn't but it does.  But in IE, I see it trying to set the header but the cookie is not there after their page loads.

Comment: How do you know? Can you post your code which is telling you the cookie is not there?

Comment: I'm using Fidler to see the calls to my domain and look at the header responses.  I am using IE Developer toolbar to look at the cookies on my page (and theirs) but it does not exist.  I also try to grab the cookie when I return to my site and it does not exist.  In FF everything works fine.

Comment: Who's domain are you trying to set it in? The domain of the response you are sending, or the domain of the page that is calling your javascript?