# How to set a cookie in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am developing a web application using Sinatra and Ruby. I need to set a cookie that is accessible from all subdomains. My original code was this:

```
@language = 'en-US'
cookies[:USER_LANGUAGE] = @language
```

This produced the desired effect (e.g. setting the cookie "USER_LANGUAGE" equal to "en-US"

However, it was not accessible from all subdomains. After looking at [How to set a cookie on a separate domain in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678628/how-to-set-a-cookie-on-a-separate-domain-in-rails) and other similar questions, I have tried this:

```
@language = 'en-US'
cookies[:USER_LANGUAGE] = {
  :value => @language,
  :domain => '.example.com'
}
```

When I check the cookie data, it is set completely wrong. The value of the cookie is everything inside the brackets, and the domain is still only `example.com` (not `.example.com`)

Here is the value produced:

`%7B%3Avalue%3D%3E%22en-US%22%2C+%3Adomain%3D%3E%22.example.com%22%7D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all your cookies to be accessible from all subdomains, you can set the cookie options for your application:

```
set :cookie_options, :domain => '.example.com'
```

If just need it on one cookie, you can do this (instead of using the `cookies` object):

```
response.set_cookie(:USER_LANGUAGE, :value => @language, :domain => '.example.com')
```

Comment: Thank you. Using the `response` method worked perfectly.